# I don't understand normal probability distribution...

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

So I'm on the [Wiki page for normal distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Let's say you have a standard normal distribution $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and you do the probability density plot so that when $X = 0$, $y$ is 0.4.

What does that 0.4 mean?  Does that mean there's a 40% chance that the value is exactly 0?  That doesn't seem right.  I don't get how to interpret the $Y$-axis.

Comment: No, it means that the probability that you'll be in the range $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ will be approximately $\epsilon \cdot .4$, when $\epsilon$ is small. Specifically, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\frac{1}{\epsilon} P(-\epsilon<x<\epsilon)=0.4.$ It's actually possible for a probability density function to be greater than $1$, surprisingly.

Comment: Basically, with continuous probability densities, the probability of any particular value is $0$, we need to consider the probability of being in subsets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks!  I will have to think about this.

Comment: An alternative way to think of it is that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,dx = P(a\leq X\leq b)$ where $f(t)$ is the PDF.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So this is the case for any PDF - in terms of interpretation?  So if ϵ is 0.5, that means the probability of X being between -0.5 and 0.5 in a standard normal distribution is roughly equal to 0.5 * 0.4 = 0.2?

Comment: You'll get a lot more error with an $\epsilon=0.5$ than much smaller values. The key is "for $\epsilon>0$ small." That might be a big error or .a small error. As a professor of mine used to say, "An approximation of a number is any other number." Also, it should be $2\epsilon f(0)$ - I forgot to double it since the length of the interval of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is $2\epsilon.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your plot:

[image]

Correct to four places, the exact value of the density function at $z = 0$ is $\varphi(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = 0.3989.$ (Exact computation in R statistical software, in case you're interested.)

```
dnorm(0)
## 0.3989423
1/sqrt(2*pi)
## 0.3989423
```

Areas under the density curve, correspond to probabilities. Suppose I take
a narrow interval around $0,$ say $(-0.1, 0.1),$ which is of width $0.2.$
Then $P(-.1 < Z < .1) \approx (0.2)(0.4) = 0.08,$ which is the area of a 
rectangle with base $.2$ and height $.4.$ (The random variable $Z$ is standard normal.) To four places, the exact probability is a little
smaller: 0.0797. (Smaller because the density curve is a little below $0.4$
throughout the interval.)

```
diff(pnorm(c(-.1,.1)))
## 0.07965567
```

See the red rectangle in the figure below. Can you use printed tables of the
standard normal CDF to get this answer?

[image]

Maybe you can use the height of the density function at $z = 1$ to estimate
the probability $P(.9 < Z < 1.1) = 0.4839.$ (Such approximations are better
for very short intervals than for longer ones. Recall that @ThomasAndrews' $\epsilon$ is intended to be a very small number.)

```
dnorm(1)*.2
## 0.04839414            # approx
diff(pnorm(c(.9,1.1)))
## 0.04839406            # exact
```

*Note:* If you're looking at the R code (certainly not necessary), it might
help to know that in R `dnorm` is a normal density function and `pnorm` is a
normal CDF. (Without extra arguments, the PDF and CDF for *standard* normal, respectively.)